# Angles in Inner Product Spaces

Tags: inner-products

In inner product spaces, angle is defined to be the only  $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$ satisfies: $$\cos\theta=\frac{\left<v,u\right>}{\left\|v\right\|\left\|u\right\|}$$ where $u,v\in V$ - an inner product space.

I wondered why this definition, that is abstract in most inner product spaces, converges with the geometric definition of an angle in $ \mathbb{R}^{3}$ with the standard inner product. Does someone have an explnation?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at the geometric definition of the scalar product. For vectors of length $1$ with one vector being $(1,0)^T$, this coincides with the geometrical definition of $\cos$.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply  $\left<v,u\right>$, you basically project the vector $\vec v$ in the direction of $\vec u$, which is just the same as the definition of $\cos\theta$ .

[image]

Comment: But why the geometric projection is the same as the algebric definition of inner product?

Comment: How do you define inner product?

Comment: Inner product is any operation between vectors that has 5 properties, namely
Its result is a scalar, Commutative, Distributive, Associative for product by scalar, inner product of a vector with itself is non-negative, according to Larson